# lots of Error-bars appear with geom_errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used ggplot2 for drawing my bar plots and after adding geom_errorbars I get many error bars stacked on each other (picture below).
What's the problem? I tried to draw it both in Windows and Linux to make sure the problem is not from my R version, and i got the same results.

```
ggplot(f.tm,aes(Gene,Expression,fill=Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Expression-sd, ymax=Expression+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: You don't want `stat = "identity"` with the errorbar geom. More likely, you'd want a `stat = "summary"` with the `fun.data` argument being a function that correctly returns the `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` parameters.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

geom_bar(stat="identity") is counting all the "Expression" values for each "Gene" to build each bar. It means, if the first bar has over 10 "Expressions" values for the respective "Gene", you will have the same number of errorbar values, that is exactly what appears in the image.